# How to get Table td value on span click after that remove that row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and there is span in the cell , when i click on span . it show closest **TR, 2nd TD** value and after that remove the row.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77mPc/3/)

i try but not working...

```
<table id="Table_">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><span class="abc">click me</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><span class="äbc">click me</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td><span class="abc">click me</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td><span class="abc">click me</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('#Table_ .abc ').click(function() {
 alert($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(2).html());
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: Your class name is `äbc` not `abc`

Comment: An also, `eq` function first index is 0, so if you want the second TD I guess that you should do `eq(1)`

Comment: sorry my mistake, after change it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work :)

```js
$('#Table_ .abc').click(function() {
  alert($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table_">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><span class="abc">click me</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><span class="abc">click me</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><span class="abc">click me</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><span class="abc">click me</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your HTML, the a char is written in a weird way. it should be a insted of ä.

Updated jQuery code:

```
$('.abc').click(function() {
 alert($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(2).html());
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/77mPc/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Note the two dots over the **ä**.  The code is correct when you replace a with ä.

```
$('#Table_ span.äbc ').click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(2).html());
   $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```